# Extremely weird behaviour with javascript addClass and removeClass

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was playing with [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and built my own Javascript function to trigger animation events.

This very simple function (triggered through an onClick event on a button) is only three (four) lines long, but it runs into a truly mind-boggling error.

The `anim` function first removes the class from the element, then adds it, so that multiple presses on the button will keep running the animation. Unfortunately, I found that it **didn't work!** That is, the animation runs once (the first time only), and then fails to run subsequently.

In a stroke of serendipity, I discovered that adding the line `console.log(element_name)` in line `3` suddenly made it work.

I was very puzzled with this behaviour, and so I experimented with adding other `console.log` lines but strangely only the line `console.log(element_name)` works!

To ensure that it wasn't a quirk in the development environment, I reproduced it in JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bhqr99e9/2/).

```
function anim(element_name){ //'animate' is a reserved keyword
    removeClass(element_name, 'bounceInDown');
    console.log(element_name); //Very cute behaviour!!! when I put this line here, it works, if i don't it doesnt.
    //console.log('a'); //Not all console.logs work
    addClass(element_name, 'bounceInDown');
}

function addClass(element, classname){
    element.classList.add(classname);
}

function removeClass(element, classname){
    element.classList.remove(classname);
}
```

Comment: And post an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Note that if what you describe really happens, it has nothing to do with the code you've posted, and everything to do with animate.css.

Comment: My apologies! accidentally submitted the question through a mispress of the Tab and Enter keys... building a JSFiddle now

Comment: @T.J Crowder I have added a JSFiddle link.

Comment: @LieuZhengHong: The full content of your question goes **in** your question, not just linked.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Noted, thank you. I notice that this question has been marked as duplicate, and it is indeed one, so I will not make any further edits to this duplicate question.

Comment: Excellent find by @Bergi.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the javascript compilers try to do several actions at a time, so your class never gets deleted!
The solution for this is to make a reflow of the page and you can do it for example like this:

```
document.body.clientHeight;
```

Change the log to that and problem solved!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your explanation and solution are correct, but can you explain why `console.log(element_name)` works while other `console.log` commands don't?

Comment: That is because if your browser has to get an element, it fires a reflow. There are many other things that would (at the beginging I used a 15ms setTimeout) but I think the one I showed you is the best.

Comment: @LieuZhengHong: Because logging the `element_name` accesses its properties, and some of them (like `clientLeft` etc) trigger a reflow when being computed (and the DOM notices that class is absent and starts the animation)